# How do I insert multiple rows into temporary tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using variable to store multiple rows and I want to insert it into temporary table.
This query returns multiple rows

```
  BEGIN 
    SELECT id INTO 
    temp_var 
    FROM TABLE_1 a,
         TABLE_2 b
    where a.id =b.id; 
     EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        temp_var := NULL;
      END;
```

I want to insert variable values into temporary table?

Comment: None. I don't know if its feasible

Comment: What is the type of `temp_var`?

Comment: VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)

Comment: You insert into a table using [`INSERT`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9015.htm). There are examples at the bottom of the page.

Comment: From your comment below it looks like you know that you want to use a GTT to store various information gathered from several tables presumably to use in a PL/SQL block. Please edit your question to reflect what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: when you say "temporary table" you mean the SQL Server usage, which is a PL/SQL collection in Oracle.

Here a variable `temp_var` is a nested table with a composite structure which matches the projection of `table_1`.

```
declare
   type table1_nt is table of table_1%rowtype; 
   temp_var table1_nt;
begin
   select *
   bulk collection into temp_var
   from table_1;
   ....
end;
```

This gives you the contents of `table_1` in an array which you can work with in PL/SQL. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#CHDHIGFH).

Given your revised requirement, it's easy enough to work with a single attribute instead:

```
declare
   type id_nt is table of varchar2(20);  -- table_1.id%type
   temp_var id_nt;
begin
   select a.id
   bulk collection into temp_var
   from table_1 a,
       join table_2 b
          on a.id =b.id; ;
   ....
end;
```

Comment: I select values to multiple tables not only table_1. I meant Global Temporary Table

Comment: Well **please edit your question** to explain your requirement more clearly